# Javascript syntax problem (find the max value)

Tags: javascript

The code is find the max value

1. How this code work

```
// this is original code
const items = [
    { id: 0 },
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 }
]

function id(items) {
    const maxId = items.reduce((maxId, items) => 
        Math.max(items.id, maxId), -1
    )
    return maxId + 1
}
console.log(id(items))  // I get 3
```

The reduce methods callback `(maxId, items) => Math.max(items.id, maxId), -1`

I can not figure out what is this, it just return `something, -1`

I never seem this syntax ever.

A **comma** between two value, what I expect is return `[ , ]` or `( , )`

---

2. Why this code get different result

I also tried this below, I think its same code above. But result is not same.

```
// I changed something, I add { return  something in reduce callback }
const items = [
    { id: 0 },
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 }
]

function id(items) {
    const maxId = items.reduce((maxId, items) => {   // Here
            return Math.max(items.id, maxId), -1     // add
        }                                            // { return }
    )
    return maxId + 1
}
console.log(id(items))  // I get 0
```

Comment: [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#how_reduce_works_without_an_initial_value) takes two parameters, a function and a starting point ---- in the above case, the function is `(maxId, items) => Math.max(items.id, maxId)` and the starting value is `-1`

Comment: Minus one should come outside of function callback in `array#reduce`, -1 in the first snippet is the initial value.

Comment: Thanks for reply comment, In this case, reduce takes initial value.
I make mistake here.